# Katalon Studio to manage dependencies in Gradle

Tags: groovy, gmail-api, katalon-studio, katalon

I try to use `build.gradle` file in Katalon Studio project to declare dependencies. Project is to make requests to the Gmail API.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev83-1.23.0'
}
```

When I try to import classes in a new keyword, I get following error:

> Groovy:unable to resolve class com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail

Comment: I can't reproduce that.  Is it possible that the studio is out of sync with what is in your `build.gradle`?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown : How could I sync it?